# Specific cast is not valid while converting SQL Server data to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server

[image: DB]

Database:

I try to convert SQL Server data to an array, but I got an error:

> Specific cast is not valid

This is my code:

```cs
string query = "select part1,part2,part3 from Table_3 where id ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
int[] arr = new int[] { };
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

SqlDataReader myReader;

try
{
    con.Open();

    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        arr[i] = myReader.GetInt16(1);
        i = i+1;
    }

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(arr[0].ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Also: where have you **defined** and **initialised** the `arr` array variable??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for `Table_3`.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: this line arr[i] = myReader.GetInt16(1);

Comment: what is the datatype of columns? if integer, then try GetInt32(1) method, then you might get "index out of exception" exception as the array length is zero. So you need specify some length to array

Comment: Note: from the data shown, it is *also* possible that `part1`, `part2` and `part3` are `bit` columns, in which case you'll want `bool` / `GetBoolean`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. The *most likely immediate* problem is that the data is not in fact `Int16` - usually `Int32` (`int`) is more common, so the `GetInt16` is probably wrong.

Arrays are not resizeable. If you create a zero-length array, it will **always be zero length**. You cannot add any values to it.

I find it *curious* that you're reading four columns but only consuming the second one - but that won't actually cause a failure.

You only seem to actually *want* the first value, not all of them - is an array even needed?

There are a few things relating to disposing the reader, but they're easily fixed.

And: never ever concatenate input into SQL.

The easiest way to fix all of these is with a tool like "Dapper":

- it knows how to convert between primitive types
- it makes it easy to correctly handle readers
- it makes it easy to correctly parameterize inputs
- it makes it easy to handle results as lists, arrays, etc

```cs
int[] arr = con.Query<int>("select part2 from Table_3 where id = @id",
    new { id = textBox1.Text }).ToArray();
```

or for just the single (first) result:

```cs
int val = con.QueryFirst<int>("select part2 from Table_3 where id = @id",
    new { id = textBox1.Text });
```

Note: if the data is actually defined as `bit`, then you'll want `bool`/`Boolean` in .NET.

Comment: @Harish I literally did - the code shown does use "Dapper", though - which is free and readily available from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/